# All the toolbar buttons of Froala

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toolbar, froala

I would like to know the name of all the toolbar buttons of Froala (https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor). I know the following ones:

"undo", "redo", "bold", "italic", "underline", "strikeThrough", "selectAll", "paragraphStyle", "subscript", "superscript", "paragraphFormat", "fontFamily", "fontSize", "align", "formatOL", "formatUL", "outdent", "indent", "quote", "color", "emoticons", "insertTable", "createLink", "insertImage", "insertVideo", "insertFile", "fullscreen", "html", "save"

I miss at least the Insert Horizontal Line button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the Insert Horizontal Line button. It is "insertHR".

Answer (score 5):

There is an example with all possible feature of froala on their official page:
https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/full-featured

```
toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new FroalaEditor('#froala-editor',  {
    toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', '|', 'emoticons', 'specialCharacters', 'insertHR', 'selectAll', 'clearFormatting', '|', 'print', 'help', 'html', '|', 'undo', 'redo','trackChanges','markdown']
});
```